# Android - How to prevent email app from being misused for spamming?

Tags: android, email, spam-prevention

I'm building an Android app that lets user send emails. (Delivered via PHP)
How to prevent the app from being misused for spamming?

Comment: Um... don't include any bugs that would let 3rd party code access your code? Is this a trick question, or are you purposefully withholding important details hoping someone will engage you in conversation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spammers want to reach lots of people, so you can meter the sending rate.  Don't allow more than, say, 10 recipients on a single message.  Don't allow messages to be sent more often than one per 30 seconds.  Don't support scripted sending (i.e., don't handle broadcast Intents).  Display a warning if the app tries to email more than 3 sequential entries in Contacts.  If you really want to go all the way, analyse the content of the email and compare it to known spam.